# How to create a ListView with an argument | Django 1.6?

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 1.6 with python v.2.7.1

I have a model Category (id,title,slug) and Films that belong to a category.
I want simply to create a generic ListView to see all the films in one category.
For example : http://example.com/drama/ and then I can see all the films that belong to that category.

So here's what I've done in views.py :

```
class CategoryListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'blog/category.html'
    context_object_name = 'category_by_slug'    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Category.objects.filter(slug=self.args[0])
```

and in urls.py

```
url(r'^category/([\w-]+)/$', views.CategoryListView.as_view(), name='category'),
```

(I have also created a simple view category.html)

but when I try to go to myexample.com/myapp/category/drama I have a 404 not found error, although this category exists

What is wrong with my code ? Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you probably want is a DetailView for Categories (then iterate over content in the template). E.g.

```
url(r'^category/$', CategoryListView.as_view()),
url(r'^category/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', CategoryDetailView.as_view()),
```

If you want subcategory features or use detail views as list views, either add a queryset to context or change the view's flow (you're probably better of creating a custom view for the latter).